# Identify automation populating a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, automation

I need to know which Automation is filling in a Data Extension (DE), the only way I know is to open the Automation one by one and see if it fills in my DE.
Is there a faster way to search for it?
Are the automations stored in DE? Can you do a search?
Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear what is a DS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry DS as DE.

Comment: Are the Automation stored in a DE, to be able to be consulted?

Comment: I have a blog post that might help: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/05/20/inventory-of-data-extensions-and-their-data-sources/

Comment: if anything, API is the way to go; still, a potential quick fix: if you are ok with limiting your search to SQL queries, go to Automation Studio >> Activities >> SQL queries, where you'll get a list overview of all target DEs, which at least is faster than clicking through all automations. As stated by others, there are multiple other sources not covered by this approach (I'll add custom script to the list).

Answer (score 1):

This is not readily available information.  Multiple Automation Studio activities can populate a Data Extension -- Imports, Queries, Filter Definitions, Filter Activities.

There's no way to search through each Automation without using the SOAP API or (WSProxy) to build some sort of inventory.